# Adding/replacing partial slug values to full url

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with postgres and I have a slug column like this below.

```
slug     
va-1          
va-22    
va-333   
va-4444   
va-55555
```

But, how can I transform those slug values to a fixed url like below?

```
full_url     
https://catworld.com/va-1         
https://catworld.com/va-22   
https://catworld.com/va-333   
https://catworld.com/va-4444   
https://catworld.com/va-55555
```

Is it possible to add those to a full_url by using case when on postgres? or any other idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `select 'https://catworld.com/'||slug as full_url`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are the best! It works. Thank you :D